# select all items and related items in one query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm using latest codeigniter

I'm trying to get all products from the db and all related items for each product. Haven't coded for a while so I got stuck on output..

Here's my model:

```
   public function collections() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->join('product_images', 'product_images.from_set = products.img_set_ref');
        $this->db->order_by('products.id');

        $q = $this->db->get();         

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {       
            return $q->result();        
        }
        return false;               
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public function products() {   
    $this->load->model('Frontend'); 
    $page_data['results'] = $this->Frontend->collections();       
    $this->load->view('collections', $page_data);           
}
```

This is the output I'm trying to get (example of two products):

```
            <div class="pr"> //product 1
            <a href="img/pr_1.jpg" rel="gallery01"><img src="img/pr.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="img/pr_2.jpg" rel="gallery01"><img src="img/pr.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="pr"> //product two
            <a href="img/pr_12.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery02"><img src="img/pr.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="img/pr_22.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery02"><img src="img/pr.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
```

I can't figure out how to properly echo products in foreach loop in the view so that they were in structure like above. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I would need a *fast'n'dirty* way, I'd go with building a temporary array of images per product

```
$groupedProducts = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
     if (!array_key_exists($product['id'], $groupedProducts) {
         $groupedProducts[$product['id']] = $product;
         $groupedProducts[$product['id']]['images'] = array();
     }
     $groupedProducts[$product['id']]['images'][] = $product['product_images.url'];
}
```

Then iterate

```
foreach ($groupedProducts as $product) {
    // output some description, title, price, etc.
    foreach ($product['images'] as $imageUrl) {
        echo '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'">';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i see your controller so that i can see how your data going to view. 
In controller:

```
$result[image] = $this->your modelname->model function()
```

Pass the image array like this to view:

```
$this->load-view(your view name,$result)
```

In view :
Place the foreach like this :

```
foreach ($image as images):
    $variablename = $images['column name'];

Echo $variable;

endforeach;
```

Colum name is yoir database colum name which you want to fetch

Comment: this will just output every image... I need to group them under each product that they are related to.

Answer (score 0):

Either use two queries inside the collections function or write a second function to get the products.

In the new function fetch these products and pass them as a parameter to your collection function. Inside the collection function you could write a query using the `IN` statement or do a foreach loop and query the database each time and build your array the way you like.

Using the in statement you could have something like:

```
"WHERE your_field IN ("'.implode('", "', $products) . "')"
```

and then go through the result and match the field and build your array.

Using the foreach

```
foreach($products as $key => $product){
      $myarray[] = .... write your query and get the result
}
```